# how to Link R in Qgis

Tags: r, hyperlink, qgis

I'm working with a large neighborhood shapefile where I always have to search three fields of 85 to find some polygons. In that case,
I'm filtering by neighborhood name, block and land number.
But, to make it easier, I extracted the attribute table in Qgis, and read it in R, as in the code below.

```
  t(df[which(df$BLOCK== 38 &
             df$NEIGHBHOOD =="SAUDADE"&
              df$NUMBER==123), c(1,2,5,7:11,19)])&  ##Other columns that I need information
```

This is the R summary:

[image]

and the specific property in Q gis.

[image]

However, I think it's possible, and would be great, to get a code that can link directly to the search R to Qgis software
and open the specified polygon highlighting it by color . I've use R because I need a summary only some columns. In addition,
I need to visually observe the polygon overlaid under an orthophoto and other layers, to compare some changes.

In short, I'm currently working on both platforms, R and Qgis, separately, in R I get the summary I need, and in Qgis I do the visual check of the polygon. However, the work is slow and tiring and I wanted to make it more practical.

Unfortunately I was not able to make a reproducible model.

If someone helps me I appreciate it.

Comment: Check out the recently released [`qgisprocess`](https://r-spatial.github.io/qgisprocess/index.html) package, you might find it interesting for your usecase (I've never used it so I don't know if that does what you want)